# SFDX CLI error in VS code

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

I have installed SFDX CLI along with Node JS, when I execute any command in console, I am getting as the attached image, I tried to get help from google, but find none, any hint from expert will be helpful

```
Error running the Salesforce CLI
C:\Program Files\sfdx\client\node_modules\@oclif\plugin-help\lib\command.js:8const { underline, bold, } = chalk_1.default; “TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'underline' of 'chalk_1.default' as it is undefined at
Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\sfdx\client\node_modules@oclif\plugin-help\lib\command.js:8:9) at Module._compile (C:\Program Files\sfdx\client\node_modules\V8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30) at
Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cs/loader.js:1157:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14) at Module.require
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) at require (C:\Program Files\sfdx\client\node_modules v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program
Files\sfdx\client\node_modules\@oclif\plugin-help\lib\index.js:7:19) at Module._compile (C:\Program Files\sfdx\client\node_modules v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js
(internal/modules/cs/loader.js:1157:10)
```

[image]

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using (`sfdx version`)? Have you tried updating to the latest version? What plugins do you have (`sfdx plugins:list`)? Anything else you can think of?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "...installed SFDX CLI along with Node JS"? Do you mean you already had Node.js installed, and you subsequently installed SF CLI? Or you installed them individually but in succession? How did you install SF CLI - via `npm` (or `yarn`) or with the download from Salesforce? I am assuming you are on Windoze, err...Windows (10?) because of the folder paths seen in your error text, but that would be good information to include when asking a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

After I installed 32 bit of SFDX CLI the problem resolved. Not sure how.